# Qt Webkit Enable Cookies

Tags: qt, cookies, qwebview, qnetworkaccessmanager

By default are cookies enabled or disabled on Qt WebKit's QWebView?

I've seen on multiple forums to create a cookie jar and add it to the NetworkAccessManager like so:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *myNam = new QNetworkAccessManager();
myNam->setCookieJar(new QNetworkCookieJar());
webView->setNetworkAccessManager(myNam);
```

Does the QNetworkAccessManager take care of adding to and removing from the cookie jar or do I need to manage that? Is this all there is to it if we just want to enable cookies and not do anything fancy?